Wavefunctions in heterostructures
Bloch's theorem applies to periodic potentials and therefore to periodic lattices. But not all solids have a periodic structure, some have an amorphous structure or may be a composite of different lattices. How does the wavefunction behave in these situations, in particular, in heterostructures? I assume each region has its own Bloch wavefunction, but what about the junction of both regions? The wavefunction must be continuous here, it must follow some boundary conditions that will have an effect on the wavefunction in both regions.

I might suggest closing this question and asking it as two separate questions. Heterostructures (where two or more materials are layered together) and amorphous systems are both huge topics in there own right and it would be difficult to summarize either in a single response, let alone both

I agree. I'll start with the question on amorphous solids. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll close this one. EDIT: I don't want to delete it, so I need a couple more votes to close it, if anyone's willing to do the "dirty work".

Why not just edit this one to include only one question and then ask a second?

That works too!

I think what you are looking for is the Envelope Function Formalism/Approximation. See for example https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.54.1909

Not a general answer, just an example of how to write a Bloch ansatz for a simple heterostructure. Consider Bernal-stacked bilayer graphene. There are four atoms per unit cell, denoted by $\mathcal{B}=\left\{A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2\right\}$, where the subscript refers to the layer the atom resides in (subscript 1 for bottom, 2 for top). In the Bernal stacking, atom $A_2$ sits directly on top of $B_1$. We assume that an electron on any atom can hop to any of its three in-plane nearest neighbours with strength $t$. In addition, we consider hopping from $B_1$ to $A_2$ or vice-versa with strength $t_\perp$. It is possible to write a solution to this system in the Bloch form
$$
\lvert \vec{k}\rangle\propto\sum_{n_1,n_2}\:\sum_{\alpha\in\mathcal{B}} e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{R}}\,\psi_\alpha\lvert n_1,n_2;\alpha\rangle
$$
where $n_1,n_2\in\mathbb{Z}$ are integers, $\left\{\vec{a}_1,\vec{a}_2\right\}$ are unit cell vectors, and $R=n_1\vec{a}_1+n_2\vec{a}_2$ is the location of the unit cell labelled by some fixed values of $n_1$ and $n_2$. The Hamiltonian in the basis $\left\{\psi_{A_1},\psi_{B_1},\psi_{A_2},\psi_{B_2}\right\}$ reads
$$
H=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&-tf_{\vec{k}}&0&0\\
-tf_{\vec{k}}^* & 0 & -t_\perp & 0\\
0 & -t_\perp & 0 & -tf_{\vec{k}}\\
0 & 0 & -tf_{\vec{k}}^* & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where, with an appropriate choice of unit cell vectors
$$
f_{\vec{k}}=1+e^{-ik_1}+e^{-ik_2},\quad
\vec{k}=\left(k_1/2\pi\right)\vec{b}_1+\left(k_2/2\pi\right)\vec{b}_2
$$
and $\left\{\vec{b}_1,\vec{b}_2\right\}$ are the reciprocal lattice vectors. The eigenvalues of $H$ are the four energy bands of the bilayer graphene; namely
$$
E_{\vec{k}}
=\pm\frac{t_\perp}{2} \pm \sqrt{\lvert f_{\vec{k}}\rvert^2+\frac{t_\perp^4}{4}}
$$
where each $\pm$ can be chosen independently.

Here $t$ is the hopping parameter/tight binding integral, correct?

That's right. Both $t$ and $t_\perp$ are hopping parameters - $t$ is the parameter for in-plane hopping, while $t_\perp$ is the parameter for out-of-plane hopping (from an $B_1$ to an $A_2$ atom or vice-versa). The hopping parameters are different because the out-of-plane atomic separation is larger than the in-plane atomic separation, so $t>t_\perp$ (from what I remember, $t\sim3~\mbox{eV}$, while $t_\perp\sim0.3~\mbox{eV}$). There are more hopping parameters, of course, to account for e.g. $A_1\rightarrow B_2$ hopping; I've just considered the most basic model of Bernal bilayer graphene.
